# java parse date from reactjs

Tags: java, reactjs

I have a reactjs front end application. It selects date and sends to java backend.
In java, my code to parse date  is :
The input date is `Mon Aug 18 2014 18:11:54 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)`

what should be my date format ?

```
    String inputdate = "Mon Aug 18 2014 18:11:54 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)";
    DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM yy hh:mm:ss (z)");
    try {
        Date r=dateformat.parse(inputdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change DateFormatter pattern to the following one:

```
String inputdate = "Mon Aug 18 2014 18:11:54 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)";
DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d y H:m:s 'GMT'z");
try {
    Date date=dateformat.parse(inputdate);
    System.out.println(date.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, my suggestion would be to convert the date in milliseconds using and send it to backend.

**JS/React**

```
var dateInMilliSecs = new Date().getTime(); // Let's say dateInMilliSecs=1576423777189
```

**Java**

```
long dateInMilliSecs = 1576423777189L;
Date date = new Date(dateInMilliSecs);
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
```